# Book about illiterate poet hobo travelling around a future "utopia" world controlled by an AI

Tags: story-identification, novel, artificial-intelligence, virtual-worlds

Once more, I'm on a hunt for a sci-fi book which I read many many years ago.  Aside from the plot, one thing I remember is that it had a painted cover similar to that favoured by Baen/Roc/etc.

Unfortunately, I'm a bit more hazy about the details of the story.

The story was set in a nominally utopian and advanced society, ran by an AI.  The only person who's refused to accept the status quo is the main character, who is an illiterate and overweight poet/hobo.

The story starts with him hitching a lift on an underground monorail, and using a bag of soil/liquid to cushion himself from the g-forces of acceleration.  When he gets off the train, he meets a Spanish/Mexican(?) man, who was the train's controller, and has a chat with him about who he is and why he's travelling this way.

> One thing I do remember, is that when things come tumbling down and the trains run out of control, the controller guy just lights up a spliff and thinks about his family while waiting to die

He's also quite fond of saying "I yam" rather than "I am", which in truth is the main thing which made the story stick in my head!

Meanwhile, the AI is monitoring this guy, as he's the one random/free factor in the world which can help it to deal with a disaster which is about to hit this civilisation.  I *think* this was tied into some political or conspiracy shenanigans, but my memory is fairly hazy on the middle part of the book.

What I do remember is that towards the end of the book, the poet gets pulled into VR (possibly after dying?) and undergoes a bit of a lawnmower-man training/learning thing, which then gives him the ability to help (or possibly replace; again, the memories are vague!) the AI which was overseeing things.  Though as alluded to in the spoiler above, things do get catastrophic before that.

And that's pretty much all I remember, bar a bit about the very end of the story, when I think the poet's VR representation has a chat with a kid in the real world while working on the post-story restoration of society.

So as ever, any hints to help find this title would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please narrow down "many many years ago"? Would that be before 1950, say?

Comment: Mid-90s/early 00s.  So around 25 years ago.

From what I recall of the writing style and content, it was probably written in the 90s - and as mentioned above, it had a relatively modern Baen-style cover (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freehold_(novel) ) - unfortunately, i can't really remember much about the cover other than the fact that it used the standard Baen/Roc house style!